# What's the best way to pass a huge collection to a Spring Batch Step?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

`Use case:`

1. A one-time read of data set X (from database) into a Collection C. [Collection size could be say 5000]
2. Use Collection C to process/enrich items in a Spring Batch Step (say enrichStep)

If C is much greater than what can be passed via ExecutionContext, how can we make it available in the ItemProcessor of the enrichStep?

Comment: Why can't use chunk processing? Do you need full collection items in enrich step?

Comment: Chunk processing is being done for the enrichStep. The Collection C may just hold about 5000 objects. I think we wouldn't want to load the  Collection C from database for each chunk execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `enrichStep` add a [`StepExecutionListener.beforeStep`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html) and load your huge collection in a `HugeCollectionBeanHolder` bean.
In this way you will load collection only once (when step start or re-start) and without persist it into execution context.
In your enrich processor wire the `HugeCollectionBeanHolder` to access huge collection.

```
class HugeCollectionBeanHolder {
 Collection<Item> hudeCollection;

 void setHugeCollection(Collection<Item> c) { this.hugeCollection = c;}
 Collection<Item> getHugeCollection() { return this.hugeCollection;}
}

class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Input,Output> {
 HugeCollectionBeanHolder hcbh;

 void setHugeCollectionBeanHolder(HugeCollectionBeanHolder bean) { this.hcbh = bean;}

 // other methods...
}
```

You can also look at [Spring Batch: what is the best way to use, the data retrieved in one TaskletStep, in the processing of another step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873762/spring-batch-what-is-the-best-way-to-use-the-data-retrieved-in-one-taskletstep/19901072#19901072)

Comment: I don't this so, but I suppose - when I answered to this question - OP use collection as a r/o collection